# Transform string with optional full names to name and initial

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to transform a string with names into a string with names and initials separated by comma.

**Example**

```
Any-Name Tom, Name Brian Joe, Smith Judie, et al.
Any-Name T., Name Brian J., Smith J., et al.
Any-Name T, Name B J, Smith J, et al.
Any-Name Tom,Name Brian Joe,Smith Judie, et al.
```

...should all get

```
Any-Name T, Name BJ, Smith J, et al.
```

The `et al.` is optional. So...

```
Any-Name Tom, Name Brian Joe, Smith Judie
```

... should get

```
Any-Name T, Name BJ, Smith J
```

I tried to do it in this way:

```
var names = string.split(",");
names.forEach(function(name) {
    name = name.trim();
    var parts = name.split(" ");
    parts.forEach(function(part, index) { 
        if (index > 0) {
            var initial = part.slice(0,1);
            // get upper case
        }
    });
});
```

But this seems to be a bit to complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost through.

This proposal uses [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for connecting the parts of the name and applies the wanted uppercase initial.

The `'et al'` could be ckecked with an upper case string if necessary. If one found, then it is later added to the result.

```js
function reName(string) {
    var names = string.split(","),
        etal = names[names.length - 1].indexOf('et al') !== -1 ? names.pop().trim() : '',
        condensed = names.map(function (name) {
            return name.trim().split(" ").reduce(function (r, part, index) {
                return index ? r + part[0].toUpperCase() : part + ' ';
            }, '');
        });

    etal && condensed.push(etal);
    return condensed.join(', ');
}

console.log(reName('Any-Name Tom, Name Brian Joe, Smith Judie'));
console.log(reName('Any-Name Tom, Name Brian Joe, Smith Judie, et al.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't simplify the OP's, but it completes it by creating a new string called newNames and writing the component parts (first names and initials & et al) to it.

```js
var str="Any-Name Tom, Name Brian Joe, Smith Judie";
var names = str.split(",");
var newNames = "";
names.forEach(function(name) {
  var neatName;
  name = name.trim();
  var parts = name.split(" ");
  parts.forEach(function(part, index) {
    if (index === 0) neatName = part + " ";
    if (index > 0) {
      var initial = part.slice(0, 1);
      neatName += initial;
    }
  });
  newNames+=neatName + ", ";
});
newNames+="et al.";
document.write(newNames)
```